# получение активного окна в Windows через java

Tags: java

Задача: Программа должна отслеживать активные окна в системе Windows и записывать их в HashMap как ключ. А значение этого ключа будет время, в течении которого это окно было активно.
Вопрос: Каким образом можно получить это окно средствами Java(или другими средствами, результат которых можно передать в Java)?Нужно будет только отслеживать активные окна и записывать общее время их работы.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Виндовые окна можно найти так:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.WNDENUMPROC;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class TryWithHWND {
   public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
      User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
      boolean EnumWindows(WinUser.WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, Pointer arg);
      int GetWindowTextA(HWND hWnd, byte[] lpString, int nMaxCount);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
      user32.EnumWindows(new WNDENUMPROC() {
         int count = 0;
         @Override
         public boolean callback(HWND hWnd, Pointer arg1) {
            byte[] windowText = new byte[512];
            user32.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, windowText, 512);
            String wText = Native.toString(windowText);

            // get rid of this if block if you want all windows regardless of whether
            // or not they have text
            if (wText.isEmpty()) {
               return true;
            }

            System.out.println("Found window with text " + hWnd + ", total " + ++count
                  + " Text: " + wText);
            return true;
         }
      }, null);
   }
}
```

Что бы получить статус окна нужно воспользоваться функцией из user32:

```
GetWindowLong
```

С помощью этой функции можно получить видимые окна следующим образом:

```
int visibleWindow = WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE;
if ((GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & visibleWindow) == visibleWindow)
{
   // если истина, то окно видно
}
```

Comment: а как тогда получить список открытых окон в Window[]?

Comment: @Владислав я переписал ответ, ознакомьтесь.

Comment: Спасибо!
А это единственный способ?Может есть попроще?)

Comment: @Владислав суть в том, что эти данные может предоставить только операционка. Так что даже если вы будете решать эту задачу на другом языке, вам придется прибегнуть к аналогичному методу.

Comment: я вас понял, спасибо за помощь!:)

Comment: @Владислав если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа)

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class WinSysUser32HWND {
    public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
        User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
        HWND GetForegroundWindow();
        void GetWindowTextW(HWND hWnd, char[] lpString, int nMaxCount);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] buffer = new char[1024 * 2];
        User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowTextW(User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow(), buffer, 1024);
        System.out.println("Active window title: " + Native.toString(buffer));
    }
}
```