# Проблема с кодировкой после перехода на maven

Tags: java, maven

в коде используется JNA. С помощью неё я получаю названия активного окна Windows. Название бывает на русском языке.

До того, как я перешел на Maven я просто баловался в простом проекте и всё работало, в консоли выводились названия на русском. Сейчас названия полученных окон отображаются так: �� ����� ����������.

Хотя если написать просто `System.out.println("какой-то текст");` то всё будет окей.

В чём может быть проблема?

В проекте все кодировки выставлены в UTF-8. В .pow прописывал всё что только можно уже.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Vladislav</groupId>
    <artifactId>Diploma</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.48.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>PCTRA.views.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Покажите pom файл что ли

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LsvKy5gH

Comment: @Владислав, гы, у меня пастебин заблокирован)))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, добавил в тело вопроса

Comment: @Владислав, а сейчас без maven всё нормально работает?

Comment: Я пока плохо в maven разбираюсь)
Если я правильно понял:
я жму скомпилировать проект и запускаю его. Символы не отображаются. До того, как сделал с maven - всё работало нормально, код не менял вообще. Разве что библиотеку вручную качал.

Comment: @Владислав, теперь если вы убираете maven, ваш код работает, как надо, или всё равно выдаёт со сломанной кодировкой?

Comment: Да, всё отлично работает без maven.

Comment: @Владислав, если без Maven и сейчас всё работает, то начинайте удалять библиотеки из Maven до тех пор, пока не найдёте тот, который портит картину.

Comment: я понял, попробую. Спасибо!Завтра отпишу:)

Comment: @LEQADA в общем удалил библиотеки, подключил заново, баловался с зависимостями - всё равно не получается у меня)

Answer (score 2):

Консоль Windows использует по умолчанию cp866.
Для того, чтобы корректно отображалась кодировка utf-8 необходимо перед запуском mvn выполнить `chcp 65001`.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете код из ответа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/465902/190934, то у меня все заработало со следующими правками:

```
public class TryWithHWND {

    public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
        User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
        boolean EnumWindows(WinUser.WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, Pointer arg);
        int GetWindowTextA(HWND hWnd, byte[] lpString, int nMaxCount);
        //** добавить возможность вызова winapi функции GetWindowTextW
        //** которая заполняет массив char (wchar_t в C++)
        int GetWindowTextW(HWND hWnd, char[] lpString, int nMaxCount);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
        user32.EnumWindows(new WNDENUMPROC() {
            int count = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean callback(HWND hWnd, Pointer arg1) {
                //** вызываем GetWindowTextW с буфером из char
                char[] windowText = new char[512];
                user32.GetWindowTextW(hWnd, windowText, 512);
                String wText = Native.toString(windowText);

                // get rid of this if block if you want all windows regardless
                // of whether
                // or not they have text
                if (wText.isEmpty()) {
                    return true;
                }

                System.out.println("Found window with text " + hWnd
                        + ", total " + ++count + " Text: " + wText);
                return true;
            }
        }, null);
    }
}
```

Так же можно установить системное свойство `jna.encoding` (либо через `System.setProperty`, либо через ключ `-D` виртуальной машины) в "cp1251", либо вызвать `Native.toString` с указанием кодировки:

```
String wText = Native.toString(windowText, "cp1251")
```

Номер кодовой страницы можно получить вызвав функцию [GetACP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318070%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Ссылки:

- Функция [GetWindowText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- Использование GetWindowTextW для [получения заголовка окна](http://ghyze.nl/wordpress/?p=196)
- Описание JNA [Native.toString](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html#toString%28byte[],%20java.lang.String%29)