# Как правильно прочитать русский символ через System.in.read()?

Tags: java, кодировка, char

Насколько мне известно русские символы кодируются 2 байтами, английские - одним. Метод System.in.read() читает один байт из потока. Пример:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    char symbol = (char) System.in.read(); //Вводим с клавиатуры русскую букву п
    System.out.print(symbol); //Вывод на экран Ð
}
```

Получается кракозябра. На экран вывелся лишь 1 байт нашей буквы, второй байт потерялся. Сделаем по-другому - добавим бесконечный цикл while, чтобы метод read() читал и выводил с потока байты до тех пор, пока они не кончатся.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    while(true){
        char symbol = (char) System.in.read(); //Вводим также русскую букву п
        System.out.print(symbol); //Выводим байты. Вывод Ð¿
    }
}
```

Опять получились кракозябры. Однако если вводить числа или буквы, которые кодируются одним байтом преобразование в char происходит корректно и на экран выводится ожидаемый результат.

Вопрос - **как правильно сложить два (и более) байт, чтобы получить ожидаемый результат в виде вывода на экран нужного нам символа?**

UPD. Запускаю в онлайн компиляторе JDK 17.0.1 на Windows 10)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос систему, на которой запускаетесь :) Есть предположение что Windows. Версия?
Так же важно указать - это обычная cmd или PS.
На линуксах такой беды не бывает.

Возможно, вам поможет этот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468674/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-maven/468785#468785

Comment: Работа метода `read` именно такова, что он читает ровно один байт. Чтобы корректно прочитать сразу два байта, можно просто обернуть `System.in` в `InputStreamReader`. Он как раз преобразует поток байт в поток символов, чтобы можно было правильно читать символы разных алфавитов.

Comment: Про InputStreamReader знаю. Я так понимаю именно он и делает "под капотом" всю эту работу. Читает байты и переводит их в символы.

Comment: попробуйте найти решение здесь - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/153328/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2